# How to solve and prevent org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException Could not instantiate Seam component exception?

Tags: seam

I'm getting this kind of error. i don't know why it is being thrown and 
how to prevent this kind of error. i am new to seam.
If someone could explain then i will be grateful.

In my view i have something like this

```
<h:inputText value="#{homeInstance.instance.sompeproperty}" />
```

Its inside the form. When i access the page it gives this error.

Thanks in advanced.
:)

Comment: You'll need to give us some more detail, especially the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: actually i have solved my problem but i don't know why this error was thrown. the error contains entityManager is null.

Comment: Again, we can do very little except state the obvious ("your entityManager is obviously null") without a lot more detail i.e. the stacktrace

Comment: im sorry i deleted my stack trace. so i couldn't trace it anymore. but its working now. thnx :)